# Recalculate item prices in onepage checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using a payment method which accepts processing payments in **installments**. When using installments the **undiscounted** price needs to be used so I've registered an observer with `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` to force the recalculation of item prices when the installments option is checked (code below).

1. walk through the one page checkout process
2. reach the payment information section
3. select the payment method
4. check the **installments** option
5. click continue
6. reach the cart review
7. notice the prices are not updated (even though the observer has been executed)
8. step back to payment method selection
9. click continue again
10. reach the cart review
11. the prices have now been updated

Can anyone explain why? And possibly give a solution to how I can skip steps 6-11 :-) ?

---

```
$installments = /* has the option been checked */

/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item $item */
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $qty = $item->getQty();

    $price = $installments ? $product->getPrice() : $product->getFinalPrice($qty);

    if ($price == $item->getOriginalCustomPrice()) {
        continue;
    }

    $item->setPrice($price);
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);

    $item->calcRowTotal();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the answer for this myself.

Apparently `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment::importData` executes `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals` before assigning the new payment data and after that the `totals_collected_flag` prevented recalculations.